# NullPointerException no Android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Estou com um problema ao listar as fotos da pasta `DCIM` no Android. Ele dá erro no laço `for`, lançando um `java.lang.NullPointerException`? O que pode ser?

Veja o código que pego as informações da pasta:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    private ListView listView;
    private List<String> minhaLista; 
    private File file;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //carrega o layout onde contem o ListView
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_arquivos);

        minhaLista = new ArrayList<String>();   

        String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        file = new File(root_sd + "/DCIM");       
        File list[] = file.listFiles();

        System.out.println(file);

        for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
        {
                minhaLista.add( list[i].getName() );
        }

        AdapterListView adapter = new AdapterListView(this, minhaLista);  
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);  
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

A classe adapter:

```
public class AdapterListView extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;  
    private List<String> mArquivos; 

    public AdapterListView(Context context, List<String> arquivos) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mContext = context;
        mArquivos = arquivos;
    }

    public int getCount() {  
      return mArquivos.size(); // Retorna o número de linhas  
    }  

    public String getItem(int position) {  
      return mArquivos.get(position); // Retorna o item daquela posição  
    }  

    public long getItemId(int position) {  
      return position;  
   }  

    // Classe responsável por guardar a referência da View  
    static class ViewHolder {  
        TextView hTextView;  
    } 

   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup p) {  
      ViewHolder holder = null;  
      String item = this.getItem(position);  
      if (convertView == null) {  
         convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_escolher_pasta, p, false);  
         holder = new ViewHolder();  
         holder.hTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtNomePastas);  
         convertView.setTag(holder);  
      } else {  
         holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();  
      }  

      holder.hTextView.setText(item);  

      return convertView;  
   }  

}
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Mudei a pasta para SDCARD e mesmo assim o problema persiste no FOR.

Comment: Felipe quando voce faz isso 'String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();' você recebe o caminho do seu sdcard tenho do aparelho se as suas imagens estão dentro do  DCIM mantenha dessa maneira, mas se não existir a pasta no seu sdcard vai acontecer como o @VictorStafusa falou.

Answer (score 1):

Felipe, veja se isso te ajuda

```
    //verifica se o SDCARD está no aparelho
    if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Erro, SDCARD Não Encontrado!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else
    {
         //cria   
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "DCIM");
        file.mkdirs();
    }
    //verifica se existe o diretorio 
    if (file.isDirectory())
    {
         File list[] = file.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        {
             minhaLista.add( list[i].getName() );

        }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Eis o seu laço `for`:

```
    File list[] = file.listFiles();

    System.out.println(file);

    for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
    {
            minhaLista.add( list[i].getName() );
    }
```

O `NullPointerException` poderia ser lançado no `for` apenas se `list` for `null` ou se algum dos elementos `list[i]` for `null`.

Vamos ver um pequeno trecho do javadoc do [método `listFiles()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles--):

> If this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, then this method returns `null`.

Traduzindo para o português:

> Se este nome de caminho abstrato não denotar um diretório, este método retorna `null`.

Além disso, o *array* retornado por `listFiles()`, quando o caminho existe, nunca contém `null`, logo a causa do seu problema é que a sua referência `file` não corresponde a um diretório existente. Portanto `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/DCIM"` não corresponde a um diretório existente no seu caso.

Comment: Victor a criação da pasta caso não exista resolveria o problema do @felipe?

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino Talvez. Mas pode ser que ele simplesmente esteja olhando para o lugar errado, e neste caso ele estaria criando a pasta errada.

Comment: entendi, talvez o que eu tenha postado não seja util para ele.